# How to run a streamlit app in a Jupiter Hub environment

Tags: python, streamlit, jupyterhub, voila

Imagine you work in a Jupiter Hub environment.

You install streamlit as follows:

```
pip install --user streamlit
```

Then I create a file as:

```
import streamlit as st

st.title('This is a Streamlit test in JH')
```

If I am in my own local laptop I can go to the command line and write:

```
streamlit run whatevername.py
```

and the app is shown in the localhost of the browser.

How can I visualise the same app if I am working in a Jupiter Hub?
I would like to be able to render such an app in the same way the notebooks are visualised by rendering them with voila.

EDIT 1:
The intention here is not only to render the streamlit app for the user, but serve it to other users of the HUB.

Comment: check out [jupyter-server-proxy](https://github.com/jupyterhub/jupyter-server-proxy) - it's a jupyter extension which forwards ports to a service URL. so instead of `localhost:8000/index` you'd host this on something like `jhub-root-url.com/services/streamlit/ad89bfa2/8000/index`. setup will of course depend on how your jupyterhub cluster is set up, but it's used by a large number of jupyterhub deployments so there should be some good templates to work from.

Comment: If I understand it correctly VOILA is not necessary to render the content of the notebook.

Comment: And if I might add another comment, in a jupyter hub, one user running an instance in the server can not access a port of other instance of other user right?

Comment: Hmm - yeah this is trickier if you want users to share with eachother from within juypyterhub. I think this is configurable, but this is also getting a bit beyond my area of expertise. Jupyter definitely makes an effort to prevent users from accessing other user's notebooks & content for security, so I think in most default implementations you'd need to create a dedicated service with permissions to serve content to all users. But there might be an easier way - not sure.

Comment: In the JupyterHub I work with there are two areas where people can strore notebooks, an area accesable to anyone, and a private area. So if someone wants to share a notebook as an application he only needs to place it in the common area, so any other one can render that notebook with voila in his instance of the hub. Privacy is not compromised at all. If this is the case it seems that your first answer is still valid, i.e. jupyter server proxy

Comment: sure - if it's ok for each user to host the application for their own viewing, and the notebooks themselves are shared, then this should work